# cx_Freeze exe file opens for a second then closes

Tags: python, cx-freeze

Whenever I try to open the .exe file, a black screen opens and flickers for a second then closes. No error shows up at all.

Here's my setup.py file:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "Robot Game",
    version = "1.1",
    executables = [Executable("Robot Game.py", base = "Win32GUI")])
```

Comment: It's probably exiting with an error, but the console closes before you can see the error. Try running it from a command prompt.

Comment: @ThomasK I tried that as well, it did the same thing.